# How to use the return value of a getter ,using reflection?

Tags: java, xml, dom, reflection

Given class Round:

```
public class Round {

    private int roundNumber;
    private Door door1;
    private Door door2;

    public Round(int _roundNumber)
    {
        this.roundNumber = _roundNumber;
    }


    public void setRoundNumber(int _number) 
    {
        this.roundNumber = _number;
        this.door1 = null;
        this.door2 = null;
    }

    public int getRoundNumber()
    {
        return this.roundNumber;
    }
...
```

and code in Main:

```
Round[] gameRounds;  

// manipulations on gameRounds , assume that we put some data into array gameRounds 

...
...
Object ret = null;
for (int i = 0; i < gameRounds.length; i++)
{

    Method roundFunction = Round.class.getMethod("getRoundNumber", new Class[] {});
    ret = roundFunction.invoke(gameRounds[i]);
    // need to put something here 
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the field `roundNumber` with reflection , but the return value is Object type , how can I use its value , i.e. how can I convert it to `int roundNumber` ? I need to write it into a new XML file ...

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into what type of object it returns? Might be an Integer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value will be an `Integer`.  Cast it to an `Integer` and then let auto-unboxing take care of it.